# Can DocuSign add signature pages dynamically?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to write a DocuSign integration where a customer uploads a PDF file and sends it to a list of signees. The customer should not have to place the right amount of anchors in the document. Instead, a new page (or several pages if necessary) for signatures should be added to the document automatically, with one signature box per signee. I want to avoid modifying the PDF myself. Is there any way DocuSign can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best way to do this would be to utilize anchor strings, which you've mentioned above that you would rather not do. Normally under these circumstances I'd recommend using a template, however you've indicated that you want the customer to be able to upload the PDF, correct?

The issue there comes down to document dimensions. If you were using a template, the coordinates for a tab would be stored in the template and be applied automatically. If your customer is supplying a PDF, you don't have a guarantee on how small or large the page dimensions will be. IE: An image taken with a Retina display vs. a 6MP camera would be like a Post-It Note vs. a calendar. The remaining option would be to find a standard set of coordinates that would work. For example, when a customer upload a new PDF always have a signature or initial tab applied at x/y: 0,0 so it will always appear at the top left.

Alternatively, what we would normally recommend is that the customer add in a unique identifier like /signer1signature/, then apply the tab via anchor string where it will be applied at every instance, even if it's a single instance hidden on the signature line.